# IF condition met take value from row above.....Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I'm new to this forum and I need your help in PowerQuery.
What I would like to do:
I have a list with expected stock changes for article. On the one hand it could be a inrease of the stock in case of incoming goods from an order which I made to my suppliers. On the other hand it could be a decrease in case of outgoing goods from a sales order. I would like to have a list which is writing the article code, the actual stock, the aamount of the decrease/increase of the change and the stock of the article after the change.
For example:

```
Row      Column1 (A)          Column2(B)           Column3 (C)           Column4 (D)

1         Article           actual stock          amount of change       stock after change

2         A                 5                      -1                     4
3         A                 5                      -2                     2
4         A                 5                      -1                     1
5         B                 4                      -1                     3
```

The stock is always the same because the changes are expected and so for the future.
In Excel this would be a "easy"solution for me to calculate column4.

```
D2 = IF(A1=A2;D1+C2;B2+C2)
```

So I'm referencing to the value above the actual row in column4 if the arcicle is still the same. But how I have to do this in PowerQuery.

What I tried in PowerQuery? I added two index columns to the table:

```
Column1 (A)      Column2(B)         Column3 (C)          Column4 (D)       Index(colum5)    Index.1(column6)

Article           actual stock     amount of change     stock after change

 A                 5                  -1                    4                    0             1
 A                 5                  -2                    2                    1             2
 A                 5                  -1                    1                    2             3
 B                 4                  -1                    3                    3             4
```

I combined this two table by the index and added the artile again in this table.
I added a new conditional column called "Häufigkeit" where a "Doulbe" should be insert if article in column1 is equal to article1 in the new added column7, otherwise "single". To get the value from the row above I for my calculation tried this code:

```
"= Table.AddColumn(#"addcolum", ""ConditionalColumn", each if [Häufigkeit]="Double" then ([colum4]{-1}+[colum3]) else [colum2+colum3])"
```

This doesn't work.

So how I can fix this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you want to compute a running total by category with Power Query. Perhaps this article will help you: https://gorilla.bi/power-query/running-total-by-category/#:~:text=Compute%20a%20Running%20Total%20by%20Category%20in%20Power,6%20Function%20for%20Running%20Total%20by%20Category%20

Comment: Sorry, for my late reply. due to illness i was only able to read the answer today. that seems to be just right. I'll read it again carefully and report back if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.  It pulls the value from the row below if article matches

If you need the row above, change each instance of [Index]+1 to [Index]-1

Otherwise please make your question less confusing

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each try if [article]= #"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[article] then #"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[value] else null otherwise null),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]